# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn odd behaviour, temporarily resizing on CellEnter

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have a DataGridView with a number of columns; one of which is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. I have set my `DataGridView.EditMode = EditOnEnter`.

My rows are set to the height of a few lines of text as this shows the user all available space for their text, however this appears to cause the ComboBox cell to temporarily resize when clicked.

Here is a screen shot of my column:

[image: ComboBox Column States]

The second, third and fourth cells are the default row height. The first cell is what is the state if the ComboBox when the cell is first clicked. You then must click again (in the now small box) to actually display the contents of the ComboBox:

[image: DroppedDown]

It looks like the ComboBox is resizing to the height of the text.

Once you leave cell it resizes itself back to the default row height:

[image: CellExit behaviour]

How I can stop this behaviour and force the ComboBox to keep it's size equal to that of the row height?

Comment: When the ComboBox is shown, it draws itself to match the height of the contents. If you want to change this, you will need to create a custom ComboBox Column

Comment: Would it be possible to intercept the draw event and set the height manually, rather than creating a custom combobox column (which I don't really know how to do)?

Comment: What you are describing as 'intercepting the draw event' is what happens when you create a custom control. In this case, you will be inheriting from the existing ComboBox and then re-drawing that. On it's own a difficult prospect under WinForms. Don't know about WPF.

Comment: if you are still interested in how to do this, I can give you some code that will do what you want. Something I have done in the past before.

Comment: I'm always interested in learning how to do something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Custom Combo Box. Add this to you project and you can drop it in a Windows Form and use it as a normal `ComboBox`

**CustomComboBox**

```
<ToolboxItem(true)> _
<ToolboxBitmap(GetType(ComboBox))> _
partial public class CustomComboBox
    Inherits ComboBox
    sub New()
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

        ItemHeight = 26
        DropDownHeight = ItemHeight * 6
    end sub

    protected Overrides sub OnDrawItem( e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        if (e.Index >= 0) then
            e.DrawBackground()
            e.DrawFocusRectangle()

            using b as New SolidBrush(ForeColor)
                dim name as String = Items(e.Index).ToString()

                dim textLeft as Int32 = e.Bounds.Left + 3
                dim textTop as Int32 = e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height / 2) - (Font.Height / 2)
                dim textWidth  as Int32 = e.Bounds.Width - e.Bounds.Width
                dim textHeight  as Int32 = e.Bounds.Height
                Dim textTarget  as Rectangle = new Rectangle(textLeft, textTop, textWidth, textHeight)

                e.Graphics.DrawString(name, Font, b, textTarget)
            end using
        end if
    end sub
End Class
```

To change the height of the `ComboBox` and the amount of space given to each item inside it, alter the value `ItemHeight` in the constructor.

[image]

---

In order to put this into a DataGridView you will need to create a custom Cell, Column, and EditControl. All three are relatively easy to create as you can see from the code below.

**CustomComboBoxCell**

```
public class CustomComboBoxCell 
    Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    public overrides sub InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex As Int32 , initialFormattedValue As Object , dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle )
        ' Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value. 
        mybase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle)

        dim ctl as CustomComboBoxEditControl = CType(DataGridView.EditingControl, CustomComboBoxEditControl)
        Dim col As CustomComboBoxColumn = CType(DataGridView.Columns(DataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex), CustomComboBoxColumn)
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = CType(DataGridView.Rows(DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex), DataGridViewRow)

        ctl.DataSource = col.DataSource
        ctl.Height = DataGridView.RowTemplate.Height
        ctl.ItemHeight = row.Height - 6

        ' Use the default row value when Value property is null. 
        if (me.Value is Nothing OrElse me.Value is DBNull.Value)
            ctl.Text = me.DefaultNewRowValue
        else
            ctl.Text = me.Value
        end if
    end sub

    public overrides ReadOnly property EditType() As Type
        get
            return GetType(CustomComboBoxEditControl)
        end get
    end Property

    public overrides readonly property FormattedValueType () as Type
        get 
             return GetType(String)
        end get
    end Property

    public overrides ReadOnly property ValueType() As Type
        get
            return GetType(String)
        End Get
    end property

    public overrides ReadOnly property DefaultNewRowValue() as Object
        get
            return String.Empty
        end Get
    end Property

    protected Overrides sub Paint(graphics As Graphics , _
                                  clipBounds As Rectangle , _ 
                                  cellBounds As Rectangle , _
                                  rowIndex As int32 , _
                                  cellState As DataGridViewElementStates , _ 
                                  value As Object , _
                                  formattedValue As Object , _
                                  errorText As String , _
                                  cellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle , _
                                  advancedBorderStyle As DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle , _
                                  paintParts As DataGridViewPaintParts)
        'base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)
        mybase.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, String.Empty, String.Empty, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts)

        if (TypeOf value is string)
            Dim valueString As String = Convert.ToString(value)

            if (not String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueString))
                Dim b As Brush = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.ForeColor)

                Dim textLeft as Int32 = cellBounds.Left + 6
                Dim textTop  as Int32 = cellBounds.Top + (cellBounds.Height / 2) - (cellStyle.Font.Height / 2)
                Dim textWidth  as Int32 = cellBounds.Width - cellBounds.Width
                Dim textHeight as Int32 = cellBounds.Height
                Dim textTarget As Rectangle = new Rectangle(textLeft, textTop, textWidth, textHeight)

                graphics.DrawString(valueString, cellStyle.Font, b, textTarget)
            end if
        end if
    end sub
end class
```

**CustomComboBoxColumn**

```
public class CustomComboBoxColumn 
    Inherits DataGridViewColumn

    sub new ()
        mybase.new(New CustomComboBoxCell())
    end sub

    public Property DataSource() as Object

    public overrides property CellTemplate() As DataGridViewCell 
        get
            return mybase.CellTemplate
        end get

        set
            Dim targetType as Type = GetType(CustomComboBoxCell)
            ' Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CustomComboBoxCell. 
            if (not IsNothing(value) AndAlso 
                not value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(targetType))

                Dim errorMessage As String = $"CellTemplate must be of the type {targetType}."
                throw new InvalidCastException(errorMessage)
            end if

            mybase.CellTemplate = value
        end set
    End Property

    public overrides Function Clone() as Object 
        Dim retVal As CustomComboBoxColumn = CType(mybase.Clone(), CustomComboBoxColumn)
        retVal.DataSource = me.DataSource

        return retVal
    End Function
end class
```

**CustomComboBoxEditControl**

```
<ToolboxItem(false)>
public class CustomComboBoxEditControl 
    Inherits CustomComboBox
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl

    public Sub New ()
        IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingControlFormattedValue = false
    end sub


    Public Property IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingControlDataGridView As DataGridView Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView
    Public Property IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingControlValueChanged As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged
    Public Property IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingControlRowIndex As Integer Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex

    Public Function IDataGridViewEditingControl_GetEditingControlFormattedValue(context As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue
        return IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingControlFormattedValue
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property IDataGridViewEditingControl_RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        get
            return False
        End Get
    end property

    Public ReadOnly Property IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingPanelCursor As Cursor Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor
        get
            Return MyBase.Cursor
        End Get
    end Property

    Public Property IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingControlFormattedValue As Object Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue
        get
            return me.selectedItem
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            me.SelectedItem = value
        End Set
    end property

    Public Sub IDataGridViewEditingControl_ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle) Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl
        me.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font
        me.ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor
        me.BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor
    End Sub

    Public Function IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingControlWantsInputKey(keyData As Keys, dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey
        select (keydata and Keys.KeyCode)
            case Keys.Escape, Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Home, Keys.End, Keys.PageDown, Keys.PageUp
                return true
            Case else
                return Not dataGridViewWantsInputKey
        end Select
    End Function

    Public Sub     IDataGridViewEditingControl_PrepareEditingControlForEdit(selectAll As Boolean) Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit
        ' Do nothing
    End Sub

    protected overrides sub OnSelectedValueChanged( eventArgs as EventArgs)
        ' Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell have changed.
        Me.IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingControlValueChanged = true
        Me.IDataGridViewEditingControl_EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true)
    end sub
End Class
```

This is then added to the Form by using:

```
grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false
grid.RowTemplate.Height = 45

Dim customComboBoxColumn as new CustomComboBoxColumn()
customComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Custom Drop Down"
customComboBoxColumn.DataSource = DropDownItems1
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(customComboBoxColumn)

Dim regularComboBoxColumn as new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
regularComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Regular Drop Down"
regularComboBoxColumn.DataSource = DropDownItems2
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(regularComboBoxColumn)
```

This is what it looks like when placed on the form. The left hand column is the new `CustomComboBoxColumn` and the one on the right is the standard `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks super useful. I'm not very fluent in C# compared to VB, but I guess the general idea is there. I'm getting a few missing reference/assembly warnings for all of the DataGridView references (e.g. `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`, `DataGridViewColumn`)

Comment: My apologies for C# code instead of VB.net, I totally forgot to check the language. I will re-write it in VB.Net tonight and repost the code. The missing reference exception should be resolved by referencing `System.Windows.Forms`